# Wacom Linux xsetwacom Attach Shell Script to Buttons

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Using Inutos Pro with Manjaro.

Would like to attach a shell/bash script to one of eight buttons.

Script would be something along the lines of 'dolphin Documents'.

Can xsetwacom do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `xsetwcom` to configure the execution of a script upon a press of a button directly.

A workaround would be a indirect invocation of the script. First you have to setup hotkeys/shortcuts (e.g. with the graphical configuration tools of your window manager or using `xbindkeys`). In a second step you can use `xsetwacom` to configure the buttons to emulate the key presses of your shortcuts.

See also https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wacom_Tablet#Execute_custom_commands